# Sorting a large gridview in C# out of memory issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

My 'senior' programmer stores grid data in a session variable so it can be sorted.

Every other day we are having to restart our server because it starts hanging up. I feel like it is because all these Session variables are floating around in memory.

Is this the best way of sorting data? Is there a best practice? We must use Stored Procedures because that's his rule. The web application is really slow and I don't know enough about *SQL* to help speed it up.

Any thoughts on if **Session variables** are the way to go? Is there a better way?

**THE LOAD DATA METHOD**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["ConnectionString"].ToString ());
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "RandomStoredProdcedureName";
try 
{
    DataTable GridData = new DataTable ();
    conn.Open ();
    using (SqlDataAdapter Sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd)) 
    {
       Sqlda.Fill (GridData);
    }
    //Persist the table in the Session object. (for sorting)
    Session ["GridData"] = GridData;

    gvDetails.DataSource = GridData;
    gvDetails.DataBind ();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Removed for brevity 
} 
finally 
{
    if (conn != null) {
    conn.Close ();
}
}
```

**THE SORT METHOD**

```
protected void gvDetails_Sorting (object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) {
            //Retrieve the table from the session object.
            DataTable GridData = Session ["GridData"] as DataTable;

            if (GridData != null) {

                //Sort the data.
                GridData.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection (e.SortExpression);
                gvDetails.DataSource = GridData;
                gvDetails.DataBind ();
            }
        }
```

Comment: FYI:  Session data is automatically freed after 20 minutes of no requests.  How big is the grid data and how many concurrent users do you have?

Comment: [MSDN DataGridView.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) There is always a better way to do things.. also can you show what the Stored procedure / query looks like.. you can can allow the individuals to utilize sorting without having to persist data in a Session Variable.. also if you are worried about size of data..then refactor the query to return a smaller subset of data based on simple things like a Date Filter just as an initial default then if needed build a `QBE` style query which will allow for a more robust execution of a query

Comment: @DJKRAZE i thi nk this is asp.net not win forms.

Comment: @SteveWellens There are about 15 people using this web app all day, and every gridview he has put the data in a session variable when it is returned.

Comment: Ben Robinson Win forms or web forms doesn't matter..the sorting can be optimized on a web front end as well.. there are many ways to better skin this cat..

Comment: @Firemarble - 15 is not very many.   How big is the data in the session variable?

Comment: anywhere from 50 to 1000 records, per visit to that page. Our SQL db has close to 10 million records

Comment: personally sounds like your `LEAD` may need to rethink the current architecture in my opinion  also the records being returned are really nothing in size in regards to returning and sorting.. can the stored procedure be refactored to implement the `IS NULL` method when passing in fields to be sorted..?

Comment: @Firemarble - I seriously doubt the session storage is causing your problems.   Have you looked in the event logs?   Maybe you are not freeing database objects correctly and are running out of resources.

Comment: `Steve Wellens` I agree with you on this one.. there is something else going on and I bet it has to do with either Objects not being released properly or some poor database performance issues..

Comment: No I completely agree about poor performance and objects not released. I just thought it could possibly be the Session variables with all the data in them.

Comment: `Firemarble` I can see several problems right off the bat..
when are you freeing the created objects in your first few lines..? why not refactor the code and wrap all of your objects in a `using(){}` that way you will not have to manually manage the releasing of the objects..

Comment: Thanks @DJKRAZE I'll do that. This is how he has been "training" me, to do it that way.

Comment: Oh my.. well I would explain to him that there are more efficient ways of doing things in today's world and I hope that he's not one of those types where it's his way or the highway.. sounds like you should be the lead..lol

Comment: Ha he's very set in his ways.

Answer (score 1):

A user cannot possibly look at more records than the number of rows shown by your grid - if your grid has 25 rows, anything over 25 rows is a waste of memory / CPU time to process. (Keep in mind, these numbers are not a'absolutes' - some applications may need more rows, some may need fewer. It also depends on how well users can look at the data and understand it. Some users work better with few rows at a time, some need many rows - this could even be a user preference but the bottom line is that pulling a huge result set is almost always a waste.)

You shouldn't be pulling more data from the database at a given time than the number of rows you can display in the grid. Sorting should be done in the database so you can return only the subset of rows you actually need. This minimizes network traffic between your web server and database server and it minimizes memory use on the web server because you only store data in the view / session state that you actually need.

If you use the view state to store the data (which is better than using `Session` because you store the data only as long as the user is looking at the particular page with the grid), that data is sent to the browser - you'll also minimize network traffic between the web server and the browser this way.

If the user tries to sort the data differently or turn to another page, just repeat the above process and grab new rows according to the new page index and / or the new sorting field.

**Edit**:

I just noticed you added a comment under the question that you usually have 15 users and return 50-1000 rows. Unless your web server has very little memory (or unless your rows in the database are *huge*) it's not likely to cause out of memory errors. Are you storing other large result sets in session variables?

Comment: Well he likes to display all records that are returned by the SP on the page. No pagination.

Comment: That's not entirely true, if I have 100 rows, I would like to make the paging on the client side rather than go to the DB twice.

Comment: @Firemarble That's a poor approach with web applications (actually any kind of networked applications). How likely do you think it is that a user can actually meaningfully look at 1000 rows of data?

Comment: @dariogriffo Sure, but 100 rows is still pretty low (assuming each record itself is small). 100 rows could probably be shown even without paging - it's about the upper limit for user attention.

Comment: I agree its a poor approach. It's why I am here asking for your advice :-)

Comment: @Firemarble There are several ways to solve this problem (you probably have other, not strictly related problems in your code) but for handling grids, most solutions will come down to only pulling as little data as possible. I didn't put any code samples in the answer because it'll be more than a few lines of code to fix this in several places in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sorting can be done in SQL. But we have to see the SP as well. I never keep DataTables in Sessions and I dont think it is a good way.

If the data is too big to get it from the database every time your developer needs it, he/she can create a view and get the data from that view. It will be much faster

Answer (score 0):

Just use viewstate instead.

```
ViewState["GridData"] = GridData;
```

It will also help if you can tell us about the size of Grid?

Comment: Ouch...What would be the benefits here..? what if you had a million rows returned would you want that stored in ViewState..? yuk

Comment: Yes, this is not a good suggestion in and of itself, although using the `ViewState` is better than using the `Session` for this purpose.

Comment: The size of the grid (rows and even columns) vary based upon the SP.

Comment: Well I did ask about the size and both Session variable and ViewState have limitations. If there are millions of rows then the sorting/searching should be done by calling the stored procedure/view with required parameters and specifing the number of rows that should be retrieved in one search say 50-100 records.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where the DataTable is disposed, there you have a problem.
My suggestion is do something like this

```
public void GetData()
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["ConnectionString"].ToString ()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "RandomStoredProdcedureName";
        conn.Open ();
        try {
        using(var GridData = new DataTable ())
        {

            using (SqlDataAdapter Sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd))
            {
                Sqlda.Fill (GridData);
            }
            //Persist the table in the Session object. (for sorting)
            Session ["GridData"] = CREATE_YOUR_OWN_OBJECTS_FROM_THE_DT(GridData);
        }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
        Removed for brevity 
        } finally {

        if (conn != null) {
        conn.Close ();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there are better ways to do this, and then you should implement the sorting, but I bet the problem is with the IDisposable objects there never disposed at all

Comment: I started putting conn.Dispose(); in my finally statement after Close(). I read that was a best practice. Your thoughts?

Comment: conn.Dispose will close the connection so you dont need to do both. Better to do Dispose than Close. But if you are doing (using Connection) you don't need that on the finally. 
I think the bigger problem is with the object in the datatable, which is also an IDisposable and those are the ones that are keeping alive. That's why I suggested to return objects and make the sort above, or, do the sort here, and return after the objects into the session, but always remeber to dispose the datatable after using it